# spl_autoload_extensions does not load classes

Tags: php, classloader

This code works fine on my dev machine (Windows) but on the server it fails to load the classes:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'class/');
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

I've checked the include path and that seems OK. I also attempted to include a absolute path thusly:

```
$application_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $application_root.'/class/');
```

with much the same result: the class is not loaded;

This however works:

```
$autoloader = function( $class_name )
{
  $application_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $filename = $application_root . '/class/' . str_replace( '\\', '/', $class_name)  . '.class.php';
  require_once $filename;
};

spl_autoload_register( $autoloader );
```

But is not as elegant.

How do I get [spl_autoload_extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-extensions) working on my production machine?

### Summary

#### not working;

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/class');
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
$filter = new Filter();
```

With `get_include_path()` I do get a complete path `".:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/home/httpd/vhosts/_hidden_/httpsdocs/class"`. I get Fatal error: Class 'Filter' not found.

#### working:

```
include getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/class/Filter.class.php';
$filter = new Filter();
```

Comment: This is probably related to the "\" vs "/" problem. Check this S.O question/answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876935/17087765](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876935/17087765)

Comment: аdd filenames in class directory. you don't need call `spl_autoload_register();` - default loader already registred

Comment: That is an interesting observatino @slashroot but contradicts the behaviour. On my Windows machine the code with `'class/'` works on linux it does not.

Comment: @WinterSilence do you mean that by just adding a directory called `class` php automachically finds the class files?

Comment: @theking2 So just curious on your linux machine after you use `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'class/');` if you `echo get_include_path()` does it show the right information? ALSO you should note that when you use `set_include_path()` it is only valid for the duration of that script's execution. Your best option is to use the `spl_autoload_register`

Comment: @theking2 In response to WinterSilence's comment you might want to read the first comment here: [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl_autoload, __autoload and spl_autoload_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987085/17087765). Very useful and will probably do exactly what your looking for.

Comment: @theking2 for example `<?php
spl_autoload_call('Foo');
$f = new Foo();` work fine if script directory contained `Foo.php`

Comment: @slashroot thanks I think I have that all covered. Unless you see something that I didn't include

Comment: @slashroot I have this in a utils.php file that I `require_once` as first in virtualla all other php files.

Comment: The following
`echo wrap_tag('p', get_include_path()); set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'class/');
echo wrap_tag('p', get_include_path());` gives me: `.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php` and `.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:class/`

Answer (score -1):

## Solved

What hinted me was the case-insensitivity on Windows OS (the file system is btw.) where linux does *not* ignore case.
The documentation on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-extensions.php) is sometimes particularly unclear or incomplete. What it didn't say is that it does a `strtolower` on the generated file (or even path) name.

I had to rename my class files `Filter.class.php` and   `YearFilter.class.php` to `filter.class.php` and `yearfilter.class.php` and so on and so-fort but at the same time keeping the class names `abstract class Filter {}` and `class Yearfilter{}` extends Filter` the classes were loaded.

Also I have to disagree with @WinterSilence. The spl_autoload_register() had to be called at least once or the class files were not loaded.

### Renaming the class files

The following code worked after renaming all my class file to have lowercase characters only.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register();

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'class/');
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');

$f = new Filter();
```

I know it works by php complaining about Filter being abstract.

### Surpassing the build-in autoloader:

Without renaming the class files (which is silly and will cause future bugs). The spl_autoload_extensions has no effect btw.:

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'class/');
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) { require_once( $class_name.'.class.php' );},true);
$f = new Filter();
```

Btw [this is already filed as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49625) and marked as `will not fix` as it will break buggy php code that depends on it. Although a [patch](https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=49625&patch=php_sql_autoload_mixed_case_fix&revision=latest) exists it seem not to have made it in current PHP releases.

EDIT: Btw the main reason of this behavior not being fixed is that whereas everything else is, in php neither class names nor function names are case-sensitive. `class FooBar{}` equals `class FOOBAR{}` equals `foorbar{}`. Having class names case insensitive it makes no sense to have the filename reflect the contents as it can't, really.

Comment: > Also I have to disagree with @WinterSilence. The spl_autoload_register() had to be called at least once or the class files were not loaded.

maybe it's true for your configuration and php version, but it's work by default

Comment: @wintersilence: state the os you are testing on