# Fatal error: Class 'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\s\wr.php on line 5

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Tried to run the elastic transoder php code from  et/s/wr.php. 
wr.php contains the php transcoder code. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;
-------------
------------

?>
```

This is the error when I'm running from the loaclhost.

> Fatal error: Class 'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\s\wr.php on line 5

So what should be done.. ? Need Help.. and yes i have included the AWS folder which i downloaded from GIT.

Comment: Are you using any php framework or is this core php code..??

Comment: running from wamp localhost and this is the only php code.

Comment: So where have you included ElasticTranscoderClient.php file?

Comment: AWs Package->C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoder.php
{my php code->C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\wr.php}

Comment: But you have not included this file in wr.php. try to include it using <?php include('path_to_the_file');?> and read the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it  this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
require_once("path_to_ElasticTranscoderClient_file");
use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient; 
$elasticTranscoder = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory(array(
.....
.....
?>
```

or user `composer` to autoload this file.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error like this.     
{Fatal error: Class 'Aws\AwsClient' not found in C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient.php on line 10}

Comment: Have you put `Aws` folder properly. It should be at root of `et` folder

Comment: if i remove the .php from the require_once. I'm getting error like this...{Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\sep24\et\wr.php on line 3} And yes i have included it properly

Comment: Can you take a look at this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775389/fatal-error-require-failed-opening-required-c-wamp-www-sep24-e-src-functio

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch the package via Composer, then you will find

- (a) your package in the vendor folder (`vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ElasticTranscoder`) and
- (b) an autoloading file at the top level of the vendor folder, named `autoload.php`.

You need to load this file. This enables the Composer Autoloader for all classes installed by it.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Or with your code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;

$elasticTranscoder = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory($options);
```

---

Maybe the folder is wrong. Let's define the root folder and require the autoloader based on that:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Its a simply include path issue.

Comment: I did that . But still getting the same error. I'll edit the question too.

Comment: It could be `../vendor/autoload.php`, because you are in `et/s`. So its one level up and then down to the vendor folder.

Comment: didn't solve the issue but instead of using composer I included aws-autoloader.php. It solved that error. Third method in AWS PHP SDK.   It created another error.. :-) But thank You though. for looking into it. Will post the error if I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Installation manual is always a good lecture :D Glad you solved it.

Comment: Can you take a look at this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775389/fatal-error-require-failed-opening-required-c-wamp-www-sep24-e-src-functio