# Composer Installation in windows Error

Tags: windows, command-line, composer-php

Tried to install composer in windows through command line. Downloaded composer.phar. Placed it in C/wamp/www/s/ folder. During installation got this error.

> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: make: *** No rule to make target `compile-json'.  Stop.

What should I do now..?

This is my composer.json

```
{

"name": "aws/aws-sdk-php",
"homepage": "http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp",
"description": "AWS SDK for PHP - Use Amazon Web Services in your PHP project",
"keywords": ["aws","amazon","sdk","s3","ec2","dynamodb","cloud","glacier"],
"type": "library",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Amazon Web Services",
        "homepage": "http://aws.amazon.com"
    }
],
"support": {
    "forum": "https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=80",
    "issues": "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": ">=5.3|~6.0.1|~6.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle":"~4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "~1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/promises": "~1.0",
    "mtdowling/jmespath.php": "~2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-pcre": "*",
    "ext-spl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "behat/behat": "~3.0",
    "doctrine/cache": "~1.4",
    "aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator": "~1.0"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-openssl": "Allows working with CloudFront private distributions and     verifying received SNS messages",
    "ext-curl": "To send requests using cURL",
    "doctrine/cache": "To use the DoctrineCacheAdapter"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Aws\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": ["src/functions.php"]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Aws\\Test\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "make compile-json"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Please add all the commands you run "during installation". We can not help without steps to reproduce the issue. Did you execute `php composer.phar` on the CLI?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\sep24\e>  php composer.phar install { and then this error came.}

Comment: You error message looks like `make` is executed. That command is absolutely not involved here. Its strange. Where is your download from? Did you download this file: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar ? I suggest to download the file again. I can not reproduce this issue. When you execute `php composer.phar install` in a directory without `composer.json` you will get the following message: `Composer could not find a composer.json file in [folder]`.

Comment: I have composer.json in that folder

Comment: Ok, seems you have problems with your `composer.json` file and installing packages - and not installing Composer itself. Please post the content of your `composer.json` file.

Comment: where to post the content ?

Comment: Please edit your question and append it. Copy paste the content, mark it as code by selecting the content and then pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: Did it. Please refer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting your `composer.json` file.

The error comes from the following invalid entry:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "make compile-json"
    ]
}
```

The `make` command will not work on Windows.

I suggest to simply remove this part of the file and try again.

(Its not clear to me, which of your project dependencies needs an additional `make` step and why you added it. Anyway this `composer.json` seems to be identical to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/composer.json . If you want to contribute to this project ask them how to build on Windows :)

---

If you simply want to fetch the aws-sdk-php package.
Follow their installation guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

Use `php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php` on the CLI.

Or add `aws/aws-sdk-php` to your `require` section and then run `composer install`, like so:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much . It installed now but the autoloader in vendor is giving error when tried to run a php program. If you don't mind can you look that too.

Comment: There is one more error that I'm getting. Can you please look into it.

Comment: This is the link->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754647/fatal-error-class-aws-elastictranscoder-elastictranscoderclient-not-found-in/32755328?noredirect=1#comment53350557_32755328

Comment: Ok, i will look into it.