# Using 'use' in included php files

Tags: php

So I have a `config.php` file with the following:

```
use PHPOnCouch\Couch;
use PHPOnCouch\CouchAdmin;
use PHPOnCouch\CouchClient;
```

Then I have another file called let's say `index.php` that includes *config.php*

```
require_once("config.php");
include("page.php");
```

And then I have `page.php` that uses *CouchClient* like so:

```
$client = new couchClient ($URL, $DB);
```

But on *page.php*, I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'couchClient' not found in page.php

Shouldn't this page be connected to my *config.php* so that I don't have to put this in my *page.php*?

Comment: You need to add `use` in the file that is going to use those classes. The `use`-statements are not inherited..

Comment: Okay thanks @MagnusEriksson - was hoping there was a way to make them inherited.

Comment: please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it

Comment: No. If they were, it would be a mess, since you would have a lot of "you can't re-declare class xxx" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Do in `page.php`:

`$client = new \PHPOnCouch\CouchClient ($URL, $DB);`

or

```
use PHPOnCouch\CouchClient;
$client = new CouchClient ($URL, $DB);
```

this also works

```
use PHPOnCouch\CouchClient as SomeOtherFunnyName;
$client = new SomeOtherFunnyName ($URL, $DB);
```

and read more about `namespaces` in php.

Little update to:

> Shouldn't this page be connected to my config.php so that I don't have to put this in my page.php?

- Every include has its own local namesless namespace or one/more named namespaces!
- If no namespace is given, you have a namesless namespace.
  In other word you can always use `namespace { /*code*/ }` in a php script
- If you are in a namespace , you have to include via `use` all needed classes.
  And because all files have its own namespace, you have to include it via `use`
- The notation of namespaces in this way: `namespace xyz;` with no braces, is for files that holding only one namespace!

A simple exmaple (just one file):

```
    namespace a {
      class a {}
    }
    namespace b {
      use a\a;
      class b extends a{}
    }
    namespace {
      use a\a;
      use b\b;
      new a;
      new b;
    }
```

lets say the last namespace isnt given, and we include this in an new file, we can do

```
    namespace mynamespace;
    use a\a;
    use b\b as x;
    new a;
    new x;
```