# php loses my "use" name in a included file

Tags: php, namespaces, include

Here is my problem, when I defined a class name with "use" in php and then I tried to include a file, it loses the "used name" that I defined in the parent file. Like this:

File1.php:

```
use \cdb\Date as H;
echo "<br> > 1 > " . H::Now();
require 'File2.php';
```

File2.php:

```
echo "<br> > 3 > " . H::Now();
```

When I execute my File1.php code this error appears:

> Fatal error: Class 'H' not found in File2.php on line 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the keyword "use" work in PHP and can I import classes with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it)

Answer (score 1):

[**Scoping rules for importing**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope)

> Importing rules are *per file* basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

You need to add the `use` statement in the File2.php too.

*update:*

If an included file are in the same namespace (`\cdb`) then you don't need to import `\cdb\Date`.

In other cases, you *can* use [`class_alias()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) to create an another name for the class in runtime , BUT it is a bit tricky and better to use a regular explicit import.

Comment: Thank's for the clarification man, theres a way to do that ? Instead of calling "\cdb\Date" only use "Date" in my included files