# Why 'use' doesn't work although 'include' does?

Tags: php

I create [PHP](http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html)-DI container with PDO. It looks like this:

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/ConfigPDO.php');
```

my ConfigPDO definitions:

```
   // ConfigPDO.php

    return [

        myPDO::class => function () {
            return new myPDO();
        }

    ];
```

And I also have myPDO class:

```
//myPDO.php
class myPDO extends PDO {};
```

I have placed class myPDO in separate file myPDO.php in the same Config folder. However, when I use in ConfigPDO.php syntax: `use Config\myPDO;` I have an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught DI\NotFoundException: No entry or class found for 'myPDO'`

and if I make `include('myPDO.php');` everything works fine. Is it right to use  include instead of use in this place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question well, but in any case, you should look for the difference between USE and INCLUDE and in what situations each one is used. I think this link can help you [Use vs Include in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139621/use-vs-include-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I know that I have to use 'use' syntax here because I do the import of the specified class to the current scope. However.. .it doesn't works this way with my PHP-DI definition.

Comment: I have found an issue. It was a problem that I have  used 'PDO' instead of '\PDO'. Thank you for your support once again!