# Laravel: 'use' statement sometimes necessary, sometimes not

Tags: php

It's quite random to me if I need to have a `use` statement to access a class. In the following code, which runs without issues, the `Faker` library doesn't need `use Faker` or something like that, yet the `Seeder` does need an `use`.

I assume `Faker` is accessed using the Composer autoloader, yet in composer.json I don't see the `vendor` directory being used for either the psr-4 autoload or the classmap autoload, so how it finds this is beyond me.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class MoreProductsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++)
        {
            $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
            \App\Product::create([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'photo' => 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
                'price' => rand(1,20000),
                'category_id' => rand(1,3)
            ]);
        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and where should I use the keyword "use" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136277/how-and-where-should-i-use-the-keyword-use-in-php)

Comment: Not really, I know the concept behind `use` but don't understand how exactly that plays out in my specific example.

Comment: Some classes are available as aliases of loaded service providers. Some of examples are `DB`, `Log` etc. You can find full list in `config/app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class multiple times, for e.g 
`Faker\Factory::create(...)`

.

.

.

then, in the same file you use
`Faker\Factory::create(...)` **again**.

Here you are **repeating** the full path `Faker\Factory`, rather you should just `use Faker\Factory as Faker;` before the class and then simply use the `Faker::create(...)` as many time you want without repeating the full path.

You can even do `class MoreProductsSeeder extends Illuminate\Database\Seeder` this instead if you prefer it.

Comment: You're right that my code could be optimized, but your answer isn't really an answer to my question