# include class with autoload.php but getting class not found error

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I tried to use [jasonmapper](https://github.com/cweiske/jsonmapper) just as written in manual.
I required `autoload.php` file, and when construct `JasonMapper` object, I go class not found exception.

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\JsonMapper' not found
```

Here is my code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

require __dir__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Games\Numbers;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request(
          'GET',
          $testurl
        );
        $json = json_decode($res->getBody());
        $mapper = new JsonMapper();// error occurs at this line
        $numbers = $mapper->map($json, new Numbers());
        return json_encode($numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new \JsonMapper();` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the keyword "use" work in PHP and can I import classes with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it)

Comment: There's no need to require `vendor/autoload.php` in every class. Require it only in the entry points of your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't "use" JsonMapper at the top of your script, PHP assumes that JsonMapper is in the App\Http\Controllers namespace, which it's not. That means in your script you must:

```
$mapper = new \JsonMapper();
```

Comment: Just tried this, and got "Class 'JsonMapper' not found" error.
Adding \ somehow resolve the original error but somehow JsonMapper is still not located.

Comment: Did you install JsonMapper through Composer? If not, you may have to make changes to your composer.json and then run composer dump-autoload.