# how do i get another variable from different php file into another file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I listed all Country names in "countries.php", like:

```
<?php
$countryArray = array(
    'AD'=>array('name'=>'ANDORRA','code'=>'376'),
    'AE'=>array('name'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES','code'=>'971'), ...
);
function countrySelector($defaultCountry = "", $id = "", $name = "", $classes = ""){
    global $countryArray; // Assuming the array is placed above this function

    $output = "<select id='".$id."' name='".$name."' class='". $classes."'>";
    $output .= "</select>";
}
```

using the file in "signup.php", well this works but,
what I want to do is to create input (mobile number) in "signup.php", In the mobile input, I want to use a country code when a user chooses a country, It will insert the country code into mobile input.
Like: user chose US +1.. in the other input it will show +1(and the user can type their own number without adding the country-code by their self)
I have also done the mobile validation properly.
I have no idea how to do the code. please help.

Comment: If the array is used only in this function, then just put the array definition inside the function.

Comment: `require_once("path/to/countries.php");` in `signup.php` ?

Comment: You should make a database table `country` in which you can put those values. Then call that table values in whichever file you want.

Comment: I already have the country in my table
and how can i use that global? it's not helping me at all, or i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on Classes. If you define your script in a class you access the variables by first calling `use myClass` and then accessing the variable statically or by creating an instance of your class object.

For example here you should create Country class and have your $countryArray as a static variable in that class that you could access using `Country::$countryArray`

Here's how your Country class would look:

```
class Country { 
    public $countryArray = ['usa', 'canada']; 
}
```

Then in your other script you could like so:

```
use Country;

$countries = Country::$countryArray;
```

Comment: in the second one i dont need to include anything?
like i have the <input class=".....>(mobile..) where or how should i mention that?

Comment: For `use` to work you should working within a `namespace`, it's not commonly used in PHP. This questions goes into a little more detail on the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it Are you using any framework here or is it vanilla PHP scripts?

Comment: Assuming you had `countrySelector()` as a function in your `Country` class, you call it on your view file as <?=  Country::countrySelector($id, $name, $classes) ?>