# Integrating PHP Paypal SDK RestAPI in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I had download the PHP PayPal SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/releases/tag/1.14.0). Now trying to add the autoload and use use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext but it is continuously prompting error message. 
`sdk location -> /application/libraries/PayPal_PHP_SDK/`

**Error Message**

[image]

I had a controller named `PayPal.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

// require APPPATH . 'libraries/vendor/autoload.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/vendor/PayPal_PHP_SDK/autoload.php';

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

class Paypal extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){  
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');        
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function index() {

    // After Step 1
    $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                'AeH73iyUSw2E_A6VRzeiyxfxR8QL9wy09XUIj5rUp42Uh9s3sQbHQTv2UdbVSx8cFGGwaapxxxxxxxxx',     
// ClientID
                'ELEN6UgB4phJT2Onwk4GjQqYyEobN_Hd-eKWlZCYMxtucsc-ZavqmKHnRSvfAknM6pjBUOxxxxxxxxxx'      
// ClientSecret
            )
    );
    echo '<pre>';print_r($apiContext);exit; 

    echo "paypal";
}
```

I had tried by composer and direct download both but still facing same error message. What am I missing, please guide your help will 
   be appreciated.

Comment: Check this you will get to know the root cause https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965466/4588798

Answer (score 0):

While not related to your specific problem, the v1 PayPal-PHP-SDK is old and should not be used.

Instead, use the v2 [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK).

---

For the best user experience, combine with the front-end https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server