# Including files with the "use" keyword

Tags: php, namespaces, sonarlint

I have a PHP 8.1 project and I use this line to include my header (it's not a class, just a regular php file).

```
 require_once 'include/cms-header.php';
```

Sonarlint gives a "major code smell php:S4833" on this" with the following explanation:

> PHP 5.3 introduces namespaces to the language. Use of this mechanism
> should be preferred to include or include_once or require or
> require_once because it solves two common problems: it avoids name
> collisions it provides the ability to create alias which improve
> readability of the code Starting from its version 8, Drupal is relying
> on namespaces to be compliant with PSR-4 standard. Drupal’s modules
> should be compliant with PSR-4 standard and therefore should no longer
> rely on include or include_once or require or require_once functions.
> Noncompliant Code Example
> require_once('./modules/vegetable/src/Entity/Tomato.php'); Compliant
> Solution use Drupal\vegetable\Entity\Tomato Exceptions This rule
> doesn’t raise issues on autoload.php or ScriptHandler.php files.

I did some research, like these pages:

[How does the keyword "use" work in PHP and can I import classes with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it)

https://www.w3schools.com/php/keyword_use.asp

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

I'm a junior developer and I don't really understand whether I should resolve this SonarLint suggestion and if I do, how I can resolve it. I don't have duplicate class names and it's my personal project, no contributions from other people.

Can you please advice what to do best? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better get rid of that "Solarlint" stuff, it doesn't seem to provide any reliable info but rather a complete disinformation

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this trigger is disinformation.

Answer (score 0):

This time you should listen to LINT, because it's a security matter.

**Problem**

Using require and include functions may lead to file inclusion attacks

Import functions :

- require
- require_once
- include
- include_once

**Noncompliant Code Example**

`require_once('./modules/Module/src/Entiry/User.php');`

**Compliant Solution**

`use Drupal\Module\Entity\User`

**Exceptions**

- autoload.php
- ScriptHandler.php

**References**

[MITRE CWE-97 1 - Improper Neutralization of Server-Side Includes (SSI) Within a Web Page](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/97.html)

[OWASP Top 10 2017 Category A5 - Broken Access Control](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A5-Broken_Access_Control)

I hope it helps you in your decision.