# Cannot use Facades Auth On PHP

Tags: php, database, authentication, connection

I try to check auth on API PHP but the result is uncaught.

This is my code on db.php:

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

$databaseName = "db_leads_v1";
$tableName = "client";

$user = Auth::user()->id;
?>
```

and it is my code on my connection.php

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'db.php';
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Query database for data
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$qResult = $con->query("SELECT c.* , p.name_pic, i.issue, u.name, MAX(a.date) AS date, MAX(a.follow_up) AS follow_up FROM client c
    INNER JOIN pic p on c.id = p.id_client
    INNER JOIN issues i on c.id_issues = i.id
    INNER JOIN users u on c.id_sales = u.id
    LEFT JOIN activities a on a.id_client = c.id
    WHERE c.role = 'Leads'
    GROUP BY id  
    ORDER BY a.date DESC;");          //query

$result = array();                        //fetch result 

while ($fetchData = $qResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[] = $fetchData;
}

$arr = [
    "data" => $result,
];

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 3) echo result as json 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$hasil = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Menampilkan hasil JSON
echo $hasil;

?>
```

and it is the error

> **/assets/api/leads/connection.php?_=1703820506660 - Uncaught Error:   Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth" not found in C:\Users\asus\Documents\FOLDER KERJA REFTECH\LeadsProject\leads-project\public\assets\api\leads\db.php:10**

I want to get database if role user is admin take all sales leads, if role user is sales just leads of here.

I wrote this code in public/assets/api/myfile.. does it have any effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the keyword "use" work in PHP and can I import classes with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965454/how-does-the-keyword-use-work-in-php-and-can-i-import-classes-with-it)

Comment: i was try that but this happen "HP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')"

Comment: Are you sure `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` is exist?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i'm sure this is the relative path vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth.php , I wrote this code in public/assets/api/myfile.. does it have any effect?

Comment: @MSaintone Are you writing code inside the laravel project or outside of it?

Comment: @MSaintone Laravel? What... It would be best if you learned how to use Laravel. Watch some tutorials, mate. ***What you are doing now is wrong(Wrong means not MVC). It's like reinventing a wheel to me.***

Answer (score 0):

If the import somehow causes problems you could fallback to the aliasing provided by Laravel.

Replace:

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

With:

```
\Auth::user()->id;
```

Or you could also make use of the `auth` helper:

```
auth()->user()->id;
```

Comment: I've tried everything but nothing works, when I try auth() an error like this appears "/assets/api/leads/connection.php?_=1703831682567 - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function auth() in C:\Users\asus\Documents\FOLDER KERJA REFTECH\LeadsProject\leads-project\public\assets\api\leads\db.php:8"

Comment: Are you sure your laravel is correctly installed? If not, please delete the `vendor` folder and run `composer install`.

Comment: im sure, i already do that and nothing change

Comment: Looking at the comment on the question, you're writing code in the wrong place. As Abdulla suggested, please move the code to the app folder to use Laravel's functionalities smoothly.