# Class not found even though it is located where I am looking for it

Tags: php, class, elasticsearch, elastica

I am trying to load a class in order for a PHP script that I wrote, with help of the classes' documentation, to work.

Since my server is running PHP 5.3, the documentation recommended loading the class like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    if (file_exists('/webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/' . $class . '.php')) {
       echo " found \n ";
       require_once('/webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/' . $class . '.php');
    }
    else {
       echo " not found! ";
    }
});
```

The only things that are different are that I included echo's in the suite of the if and else.
Also myUsername is actually my username in the file-system path on the server.

Then, it ( the documentation ) suggests that I make a new instance of the class like so:

```
$elasticaClient = new \Elastica\Client();
```

However, I am getting an error that the class is not found. Here is exactly what is printed including the error and the suite of my if-else:

not found! Fatal error: Class 'Elastica\Client' not found in /webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/index.php on line 17

line 17 is the line where I try to make an instance of the class.

now, index.php is where the above code is and it is located, on my server, in /webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/

and all the class files are in /webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/

so, I don't understand why it is not able to find / load the class.

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this!

Comment: What is the full path name of the file that holds your class (you haven't told us the name of the file.)

Comment: @MikeBrant I just realised class is never defined. For this part of the code I just wrote what the documentation had as an example.

But, to answer your question, there seems to be multiple files in the lib dir that resemble classes.

Comment: So is this an invalid question then?  If the class isn't defined why would you expect it to load?

Comment: @MikeBrant no, the class is defined. The variable $class has no value. The documentation never said to give it a value. It said the first code in an example is to have the first block of code in my question and then the second block of code right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not found!` - it's mean that the file was not found. File, not class.

Variable $class contains full class name with namespaces `Elastica\Client`. Are you sure that you have `/webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/Elastica\Client.php` file?

Check [How do I use PHP namespaces with autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload) and learn about [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Comment: ah, that is correct that it means the file was not found.

But I do have a client.php in /webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/Elastica/

Why is the last slash a backward-slash in your filesystem path?

Comment: Edited answer. `$class == 'Elastica\Client'`. After concatination filename will be `/webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/Elastica\Client.php`. Don't forget that linux file system is case sensitive.

Comment: Ah, well I don't know if this makes a difference, but Client.php is located here:
/webgit/webroot/home/myUsername/www/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php

and this is a linux server, but the path to that file seems to be the same as what it is looking for...

Comment: You must replace `\ to /`. `$class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);`

Comment: Where should I add that line? Inside the spl_autoload_register function right before it closes? Before that function? Or after it right before the instance of the class is made?
Or right before it does the file_exists ?

Comment: I put the str_replace where it made most sense to me right before the if(file_exists... and inside the spl_autoload_register()'s suite.

Answer (score 0):

Redacted due to excessive wrongness. Mike has a link in the comments worth preserving, however.

Comment: The backslash is a PHP namespacing syntax.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: I have never seen \ in a class name either. That is why I was confused by it. Yes, with the default set up of the files that I got from GitHub, the class is in multiple files in the lib directory.

1.) Ah, I didn't even think about that. Good catch!
2.) I don't full understand what you mean by issue number 2.

Yes, there is a Client.php in the lib/Elastica/ dir.

I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, the documentation called it namespacing.

Comment: I am still getting that error after removing the first back-slash and changing the second one to a forward-slash.

Comment: Yeah, after reading up about namespaces at @Mike's link above, I realize I was pretty much wrong. I'd delete my answer, but I think his link is valuable, So I'm just going to redact most of what I said.