# PHP namespace and autoload doesn't work

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have a file called Query.php.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Query
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            printf("Hello, World");
        }
    }
}
```

in bootstrap.php I try to call it:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    if(file_exists('../folder/'.$className.'.php'))
    {
        require_once '../folder/'.$className.'.php';
    }
});

new \Test\Query();
```

Result: Fatal error: class Test\Query not found.

Without namespace it works fine. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `spl_autoload_register` implementation? It doesn't magically know where to load the classes from. If you do have one, that's where the bug is.

Comment: @JuanMendes, sorry. I added it.

Comment: You really have a folder called folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the `\` with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    if(file_exists(BASE_PATH . '../folder/'. str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $class). '.php'))
    {
        require_once '../folder/'.$className.'.php';
    }
});
```

This is assuming your directory structure is the following

> /folder/boostrap.php
>
> /folder/Test/Query.php

See [How do I use PHP namespaces with autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload)