# PHP can not create instance of class with namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, instance

I've got the following problem:

This is my super basic class:

```
class A
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo "bar";
    }
}
```

Now in front of the class declaration I use the following code:

```
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

When I open the php file in the browser, the output is "bar". Fine!

Now I want to do the same thing in another file.

directly in the first place I declare the following namespace:

```
namespace model\dbAction;
```

This is the path where my file with the class above is located.

So in another php file I do the following:

```
$a = new \model\dbAction\A();
$a->foo();
```

But I don't get any output and other code after that won't run so it looks like it breaks directly after the instancing of the class.

Any ideas why instancing the class in another file is not working?

Thanks!

Full code first php file:

```
<?php
namespace model\dbAction;
class A
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo "bar";
    }
}
```

Full code of the second file (which I call in the browser):

```
$a = new \model\dbAction\A();
$a->foo();
```

Comment: Do you have namespace A; above that class?

Comment: enable display_erros and error_level E_ALL

Comment: The namespace is model\dbActions which is the path to the file. And it is declared right in the beginning before I declare the class.

When I enable errors I get the following error: Fatal error: Class 'model\dbAction\A' not found in /var/www/dgroupReporting/install/install.php on line 7

Comment: Show all of the code. Did you include the class file in the new file?

Comment: You probably didn't included a file. Or have broken autoloader

Comment: I added the full code in the top post.
I didn't includ the class file in the other file, I'm going to try that.

Comment: including works! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to `include` the file -- providing the namespace itself will not include the file for you... unless you're using an autoloader. See: [How do I use PHP namespaces with autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload)