# Why do I have to re-include a class that was already included from a different file?

Tags: php, namespaces, include, spl-autoload-register

I have something like the following:

**main.php:**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    require_once  $className . '.php';
});

use Example\RandomClass;

include 'anotherFile.php';
```

**anotherFile.php:**

```
RandomClass::example();
```

**Example/RandomClass.php:**

```
namespace Example;

class RandomClass {

    public static function example() {
        echo 'example';
    }

}
```

However I get the following warning:
`Warning: require_once(RandomClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in main.php on line 5` unless I have `use Example\RandomClass.php` in anotherFile.php as well. Is this intended behaviour and how should I make it so that I only have to require the class once?

Comment: Why not use a namespace-aware autoloader - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your autoload is wrong:

`require_once  $className . '.php';`

should be

`require_once  'Example\' . $className . '.php';`

and check 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload)