# php create instance of another class

Tags: php

I'm totally new to php(migrating from java). There are two classes

**First.php**

```
class First {

    public function method(){
        #how to call second object like java
        #$obj=new Second();
    }
}
```

**Second.php**

```
class Second{
    public function method_second(){
        echo 'second method';
    }
}
```

Can't we create object of Second.php in First.php

Comment: Yes, un-comment the code and see.

Comment: Sure, you can. The code you have should work fine.

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as you have `include`d (or `require`d) Second.php or defined an autoloader.

Comment: But, that's a dependency yes?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, of course.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I'm not a big time OOP guy, but I thought that was "bad"?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Test\Src\Second' not found in

Comment: @AbraCadaver not all dependencies of this type are avoidable. Think, for example, of a factory class. It obviously has to instantiate other classes to do its job.

Comment: @Exbury Like I said, you have to `include`, `require`, or autoload your second class; you can't just refer to it without telling PHP where the class is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the `Second.php` file in the `First.php` to have access to the `Second` class:

```
<?php
include "Second.php";
class First {
    public function method(){
        #how to call second object like java
        $obj=new Second();
    }
}
```

Also you can use an autoloader ( not the best example :) ):

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

class First {
    public function method(){
        #how to call second object like java
        $obj=new Second();
    }
}
?>
```

More info about autoloaders can be found on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: can we use without register autoload

Comment: @Exbury, No, you are forced to choose between `include "Second.php";`, `require "Second.php";` or the `autoloader`. The PHP should know where the class is defined and these are methods you should use to tell where the class is located.

Comment: Another question i have if add both classes with namespace Test\Src; Then how can we create object. if i used as this it throws exception Fatal error: Class 'Test\Src\Second' not found

Comment: You can get more info in another question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload